# trim letters at the beginning and the end of a string

Tags: regex, sed

```
# trim the beginning "t"
echo "test"|sed "s/^t//g" 
est

# trim the ending "t"
echo "test"|sed "s/t$//g"
tes

# trim both the beginning and ending "t"
echo "test"|sed "s/(^t)|(t$)//g"
test
```

Why did the thrid one fail? How can I make it work?

Comment: If it was in a variable you could also use bash `echo "${VAR:1:${#VAR}-2}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use extended regex for this: `-r`

```
$ echo "test"|sed -r "s/(^t)|(t$)//g"
es
```

From `man sed`:

> **-r**, --regexp-extended
>
> use extended regular expressions in the script.

Or you can also escape all the regex conditions, like [Etan Reisner suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383841/trim-letters-at-the-beginning-and-the-end-of-a-string/26383900?noredirect=1#comment41422270_26383900):

```
$ echo test | sed 's/\(^t\)\|\(t$\)//g' 
es
```

---

Note you can also use `-e` to indicate multiple commands:

```
$ echo "test"|sed -e "s/^t//" -e "s/t$//"
es
```

Comment: `echo test | sed 's/\(^t\)\|\(t$\)//g'` also works, at least with GNU sed.

Comment: Pretty true, @EtanReisner, I tried that but I was just escaping `|`, so it did not work. Many thanks, I updated the post with your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use this,

```
$ echo test | sed 's/^t\|t$//g'
es
```